# Javascript mongodb aggregation filter not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

It's my line of code you see below is not working! It always returns an empty array value.

Please help me!

That's working!

```js
const data = await NumbersModel.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            Datas: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Datas",
                    as: "data",
                    cond: { $gte: [ "$$data.time", lastdata ] }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

That's not working!

```js
const data = await NumbersModel.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            Datas: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$Datas",
                    as: "data",
                    cond: { 
                        $and: [
                            { $gte: [ "$$data.time", lastdata ], },
                            { $eq: [ "$$data.number", req.query.number ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working :)

```js
const data = await NumbersModel.find({ "Datas.time": { $gte: lastdata }, Number: req.query.number })
```